# Java Web Start can't open jnlp file

Tags: ipv6, jnlp, java-web-start, socketexception, proxy-server

I downloaded the file SwingSet3.jnlp from here: [java.net/.../SwingSet3.jnlp](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swingset3/SwingSet3.jnlp).
I am running a Windows 7 64Bit operating system, every time i click on the file, **java 7** starts but then gives me the following error: Application could not be started.

This is the Exception:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Resource could not be loaded: http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swingset3/SwingSet3.jnlp
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine._downloadCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**In the other tab i get this Exceptions:**

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine._downloadCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**and in the console**

```
 Java Web Start 10.9.2.05
JRE-Version uses 1.7.0_09-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
Benutzer-Home-Verzeichnis = C:\Users\Devid
----------------------------------------------------
c:   Konsolenfenster löschen
f:   Objekte in Finalisierungs-Queue finalisieren
g:   Garbage Collect
h:   Diese Hilfemeldung anzeigen
m:   Speicherauslastung drucken
o:   Logging auslösen
p:   Proxykonfiguration neu laden
q:   Konsole ausblenden
r:   Policy-Konfiguration neu laden
s:   System- und Deployment-Eigenschaften ausgeben
t:   Threadliste ausgeben
v:   Thread-Stack ausgeben
0-5: Trace-Ebene auf <n> setzen
----------------------------------------------------
#### **Java Web Start Error**:
#### Ressource could not be loaded: http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swingset3/SwingSet3.jnlp
```

**Thats** not the only problem, when i go to a site like this: [Game Of Life](http://www.math.com/students/wonders/life/life.html)
I get a Exception : ClassNotFoundException

Maybe someone knows whats the problem.

**Now i get some other exception when trying to open the file :**

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried a lot of different things. I disabled my firewall, the avira and the windows defender (this one was already disabled). I also did this: netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable

But also i installed a hotfix from windows for some FTP problems ([enter link description here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7077696)), [enter link description here](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9728869Fix%20this%20problem). I also disabled IPV6 for my internet connection.

From Control Panel-> **Java Control Panel** in settings i deleted the  Trace and Logfiles and Cached Applications. I also unchecked the box to keep temporary files on my computer.

The only thing left in Java Control Panel is to change the internet settings, i could set it to Use **ProxyServer**, but i don't know what address or port number i should put inside.

The interesting thing is that Eclipse works fine!

I really don't have a idea what i should do next. It seems also that no one knows hear also how to resolve the Problem.

---

Without doing anything, i just upgraded my Windows from Windows 7 Home Edition to Professional, and now the problems are gone.

Comment: You posted a lot of detail, hopefully you get a good answer soon!

Comment: 1) The GoL worked for me. 2) The SwingSet3 download has stalled (and looks like failing).  3) Try it with a simpler (smaller) JWS app. that I just checked moments ago - the [Persistence Service demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I tried, but that too want work. 
Also as i mentioned when i go to a site that uses Java plugins, when i trie to launch a application like Game of Life i get ClassNotFoundException. I am sure it is a problem with WebStart.

Comment: @vgoff but i don't see still any help :(

Comment: Be patient.  Know that you can edit your question with further things that you figure out as well as commenting here.  I would help if I could, but this is something I don't know very much about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without doing something regarding this problem i upgraded my Windows 7 Home To Windows 7 Professional and the problem with java is now past.

I remember also that i used **CCleaner** Programm, but i dont think this solved the problem. 
Weird, but maybe there is some problem with Java and Windows 7 Home Edition 64 Bit